# How does one parse the notion of "systemic racism" in the context of poverty?

Tags: united-states, economy, racism

One will often read statistics like: "Black Americans are dying from the coronavirus at more than twice the rate of whites." The obvious inference, here, is that blacks have less access to healthcare than do whites. The story is the same when it comes to the wealth and income gaps, as well as access to education and so on. The disparities are simply undeniable.

It remains to be explained, however, whether this lack of opportunity is owed directly to economic circumstances, or whether it is a result of an ongoing and active kind of current racism. A black person who cannot afford healthcare is in a very different situation than a black person who is denied a job in favour of a white worker directly in virtue of his race.

In most conversations, it seems to me that people conflate these two perspectives. Without a doubt, the economic disparities we observe between blacks and whites has everything to do with America's history of racism. But if this is the case, it seems to me that the term *systemic racism* is slightly misleading because it does not mean that racism is currently systemically enforced. If, when people refer to systemic racism, they mean that people are actively pursuing the maintenance of these disparities, then they have a more difficult case to make. Generalized statistics certainly do not seem sufficient to support this narrative because of the economic layers.

Now, of course, this picture is complicated by the idea of implicit bias. Sure, there may not be as many vicious, believing and committed racists running around the US as there once was. You might say, then, that these disparities are deeply aggravated by an underlying psychological bias. But again, how are you supposed to demarcate the extent to which this bias is present versus other factors?

Defenders of the term are thus left with the unfalsifiable claim that implicit (and sometimes explicit) bias contribute *significantly* to the data, while denialists can simply argue that everything can be chalked up to "past racism." What are the best ways to get around these generalizations and further (and more precisely) parse what is obviously a complex issue?

EDIT: Let me put this another way for those who are confused. We observe disparities in many areas (wealth, education, healthcare, policing, etc.) between black people and non-black people. My question is this: How might we measure how much current/ongoing explicit and implicit prejudice accounts for maintaining these disparities versus other factors (cultural, sociological, economic, etc.)?

Here is a crude example. It could be the case that more black people are arrested than whites because cops are generally racist (implicitly or explicitly). But it could also be the case that black people just commit more crimes because of cultural and economic factors. Now, obviously the issue here is nuanced, it's not going to be a one or the other answer. How can we approximate the degree to which each is responsible for the statistical disparities we observe?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what systemic racism is. [From wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_racism): "Institutional racism (also known as systemic racism) is a form of racism expressed in the practice of social and political institutions. It is reflected in disparities regarding wealth, income, criminal justice, employment, housing, health care, political power and education, among other factors". The fact that African Americans are, on average, poorer than white Americans is not a counter-argument to the existence of systemic racism, it's a key part of it.

Comment: @divibisan Okay, so be it. But again, there must be different kinds of systemic racism, here, because being disadvantaged by virtue of class is quite different from being suppressed by virtue of race. My question revolves around how much credence we lend to each given the disparities we observe.

Comment: I think you also might have something of a misunderstanding about where those relarive death rates come from.  It's not really different medical treatment, since there really IS no good treatment for the COVID-19 virus.  Instead, it reflects a greater likelihood of catching the virus in the first place, and this in turn seems likely to be a consequence of crowded living conditions, which in turn is usually a reflection of poverty and/or living in urban areas.

Comment: @divibisan: But neither does the fact that blacks are poorer than whites, on average, prove that the disparity is due to racism.

Comment: You seem to be missing @divibisan 's point. The outcome "Black people overwhelmingly belong to a different class than white people" is evidence of systemic racism. You can't separate race from class the way you're trying to.

Comment: i don't get your mutual exclusivity; racism can be the cherry on top of econ disparities.

Comment: Yes, but what causes the economic disparities? Could it be systemic racism?

Comment: @jamesqf "It's not really different medical treatment" -- well, yes and no, see one of many papers on [racial disparity in medical treatment](https://www.google.com/search?&q=racial+disparity+medical+treatment+site%3Anih.gov), such as "surprising to many are the racial disparities...where differences in [SES] are minimized such as the Veterans Health Administration System and the Medicare program" https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4194634/

Comment: @Johanna: It could, but there are other explanations that are at least equally viable.  You might consider cultural factors, and ask why poverty also persists among particular white communities.

Comment: @divibisan, to put a fine point on it, your argument is that systemic racism continues not primarily because whites continue to hold or express racist ideology or discrimination, but simply because they (as a statistical unit) passively continue to hold on to an unequal distribution of wealth and power, originally garnered in (and attributable to) an era when they did actively discriminate? In other words, systemic racism continues simply because its original distributional effects (perpetuated or exacerbated through ordinary capitalist class discrimination) have not been redressed?

Comment: @jamesqf - covid is going to have more severe rammifications for people with other underlying conditions. When talking about the disparate effects on minority communities, that's always mentioned as THE key factor - black Americans are more likely to have those other underlying conditions and not have the access to the treatment for them, both prior to and after contracting the virus. And that runs along economic lines, as well. So, not just contracting the virus, itself.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: The question that AFAIK isn't even being asked, let alone answered, is whether the effects on those minority communities are different from the effects on poor white communities.

Comment: @jamesqf - I wasn't disagreeing, just adding on some additional perspective on your comment.

Comment: I am unsure if this one is correct: "The obvious inference, here, is that blacks have less access to healthcare than do whites". Here in Denmark Corona have hit low-income as well, and the argument mainly is that low-income have to go to work and don't have the luxury to avoid the disease as effective as middle class citizens.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: Yes, and I was likewise asking for some more perspective on the whole idea of "systemic racism", and how much it is simply a matter of poverty rather than race.

Comment: @jamesqf - Your comment talked about the differences in death rates and how it related to a differential incidence of *catching* the disease as a primary factor that needed to be considered. It seemed like that left a gap, regarding the underlying conditions, accessibility and qualify of care for the underlying conditions, which also very directly impact the racial disparities. I think we're both looking for a more complete picture. Hard to get that with a virus that's only been known for a few months, though. Cheers!

Comment: "The obvious inference, here, is that blacks have less access to healthcare than do whites" <- that may be obvious to you... the obvious inference to an extreme racist would be that blacks have worse immune systems because they are genetically inferior

Answer (score 8):

Some of the strongest evidence we have about currently existing racial bias with economic consequences comes from resume studies and other kinds of **carefully controlled field experiments**. It has been shown again and again over decades that if you send employers the exact same resumes with either stereotypically white or stereotypically black names on them to similar kinds of companies, the response rates are measurable different. Likewise, it is well-documented that similar candidates with similar qualifications have different results from job interviews based on racial identity. [Here](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2017/09/11/1706255114) is a meta-study which finds that from 1989 through 2017, "whites receive on average 36% more callbacks than African Americans, and 24% more callbacks than Latinos." Keep in mind that this  is already controlling for education, experience and other relevant variables. Obviously, that level of racial discrimination will have some degree of impact on people's earnings.

However, it's unclear why the question is framed so explicitly in terms of present discrimination. Why is the past not relevant? There are even greater economic disparities in terms of wealth then in terms of income. **Wealth accumulates in families over generations, so past forms of discrimination have lasting effects.** Housing discrimination is an important example. It still exists today, but was even more widespread when formal and overtly racist [redlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redlining) was still legal. [Here](https://osf.io/preprints/socarxiv/jdmq9/) and [here](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2852856) are just a few of the many studies that have been done on this recently. Past wrongs cannot be corrected by fixing the immediate issue by reducing or eliminating ongoing discrimination; the lasting impacts of past discrimination must also be addressed before we can claim the playing field is level.

Comment: Re "stereotypically black names", is this really racist, or is it "culturist"?  That is, those names probably indicate that the person was raised in a culture which devalues the qualities that would make a good employee.  Rather the same effect as if your white candidate sported a name like Galadriel Moonbeam.  It also begs the question of why, if parents want their children to be financially successful, they insist on giving them such names.  Compare for instance to the Asian community, where children are commonly given western names (at least for public use).

Comment: The resume thing isn't actually "systemic" though, right? I mean, "systemic" as I usually hear the term applied usually does not refer to individual biases based on race (which are usually referred to as "implicit bias"). A hiring manager throwing a resume away because the name on it "sounds black" isn't very systemic.

Comment: @jamesqf What you call culturalism is what others call "color-blind racism". If non-whites need to emulate whites to be treated as equal members of society, I think it's perfectly fair to call that society racist.

Comment: @Joe I don't think we need to prove a conscious conspiracy exists to call it systemic. What matters is that it is widely pervasive in society.

Comment: @BrianZ How is it "systemic" if it's a flaw in a single, identifiable person?

Comment: @Joe I don't understand your assertion. If whites receive on average of 36% more callbacks across many different experiments, how could this possibly be the fault of any "single, identifiable person"?

Comment: @Brian Z: That's where you - and the people inventing the "color blind racism" nonsense - are wrong.  (Or perhaps "not even wrong" applies here?)  First, why should people be locked in a particular culture because of their skin color?  Second, you have pretty much the same thing happening everywhere.  Certainly I would never have been successful in my field if I'd insisted on behaving according to the norms of my (white hillbilly) birth culture.

Comment: @jamesqf These are non-sequitirs. Who said "people [should] be locked in a particular culture because of their skin color"? Does the worldwide prevelance of anti-black racism make it somehow inherently not racist? Discrimination against white people based on rural/ working-class/regional accents is real too, so what's your point?

Comment: @jamesqf also notice how (East) Asian Americans have zero problems in Western society. In fact, Western universities discriminate against Asian Americans as they're too successful in college admissions. Ditto for Jewish Americans, despite all the antisemitism. Hard work and perseverance solve all problems.

Comment: @jamesqf While I don't see the data presented on this particular study, past studies similar to this one have shown that it is the "black" part of a name that is discriminated against, not wacky names like "Galadriel." A black man with a very common and accepted name (but still stereotypical black) such as "Jerome" still shows the discriminatory effect. What "culture" do you think a Jerome lives in that makes them a somehow inferior candidate that can be explained without racism?

Comment: @MichaelW. That is correct, the classic study cited in the one I linked to is [here](https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/0002828042002561) and the names used are listed there.

Comment: @JonathanReez "also notice how (East) Asian Americans have zero problems in Western society. " - I don't think that's true (certainly "zero" is not true) and even if it were true that doesn't mean there is no racism against blacks. "Hard work and perseverance solve all problems." - lol

Comment: @jamesqf "Re "stereotypically black names", is this really racist, or is it "culturist"? " - if people are rejecting resumes with Lakisha Washington or Jamal
Jones on them on "culturist" grounds, is that prejudice much better than rejecting those resumes on racist grounds? If the effect is indistinguishable, what difference does it make what we call that prejudice?

Comment: @BrianZ My question to you was about a singular hiring manager throwing away a resume because it had a "black-sounding" name. Let's say this one guy is a bigot. If the hiring manager is an identified human being who throws away resumes because he doesn't like black people, how is his racism a systemic problem? I mean, "the system" didn't throw away any resumes, this one person did.

Comment: @Joe In a society of perfect racial justice, this individual bigot would be likely to get fired if they somehow got hired in the first place. In a structurally racist society, this individual bigot faces no negative consequences and nothing changes.

Comment: Also, it matters that there is a general pattern of managers with the same biases. If different individual managers had different biases that effectively cancelled each other out in the society as a whole, that would provide a different result then what we are seeing.

Comment: @Brian Z: The people who say that people should be locked into their culture are numerous, and quite vocal.  E.g. the people who taunt black kids for "acting white", or the ones who taunted a white hillbilly kid for being an "egghead" or "nerd" for being good at school, the ones who take any excuse to shout 'cultural appropriation" (while being perfectly happy to culturally appropriate things like jean, t-shirts, and computers).

Comment: @Lag: The question is whether it is PREjudice, or whether it is simply making a reasoned judgement, in the same way that someone who wants to hire a competent programmer might prefer a candidate with a BS in CSE over someone who dropped out of college.  Sure, I can point to a couple of good dropout programmers, but is that the way to bet?

Comment: @Lag: In any case, this is really missing what I think is the important point, which is that there are a number of black (or other group) people who seem to succeed in mainstream society, despite supposed systemic racism.  It might be more productive to ask why and how these people do succeed, rather than simply picking out something to blame for all the non-successes.

Comment: @jamesqf In the resume experiments that I'm aware of the resumes are identical but for the names of the applicants. 'Robert Jones' is more successful than 'Jamal Jones'. Perhaps Jamal should change his name?

Comment: @BrianZ Surely it depends on the specific activity in question. If "non-whites have to act like whites" by taking "more white" names, that's racism. But what if it was, like, studying more in school? This is where people are coming from when they say "that's not racist"

Comment: @user253751 Even if you were to show that certain ethnic groups are less studious than others, that hardly disproves the existence of discrimination.

Comment: "it's unclear why the question is framed so explicitly in terms of present discrimination." How is that unclear? OP is inquiring into how much of current racial disparities are due to ongoing discrimination, and how much is due to ongoing effects of past discrimination. How is that not pertinent question?

Comment: @Acccumulation OP says: "*My question is this: How might we measure how much current/ongoing explicit and implicit prejudice accounts for maintaining these disparities versus other factors (cultural, sociological, economic, etc.)?"* There's a lot of vagueness here about the "other factors", and an explicit denial of the idea that past discrimination is precisely what explains these other factors ('*denialists can simply argue that everything can be chalked up to "past racism."*').

Answer (score 5):

This question seems to stem from some amount of confusion, that discrimination operates on two mutually exclusive axes, one describing race and one describing class. In reality, the two are closely related.

A quick [example from wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racial_inequality_in_the_United_States)

> The Pew Research Center's analysis of 2009 government data says the median wealth of white households is 20 times that of black households and 18 times that of Hispanic households.[11]
>
> ...
>
> Data has shown that “among racial and ethnic groups, African Americans had the highest poverty rate at 27.4%” [18].
>
> ...
>
> In 2017, the homeownership rate was 72.5% for non-Hispanic Whites, 46.1% for Hispanics, and 42.0% for Blacks.[30] From this data, non-Hispanic Whites own homes at a much higher rate that all other races, while Hispanics and Blacks own homes at much lower rates. This means that a high percentage of Hispanic and Black populations do not receive the benefits, such as wealth accumulation and insurance against poverty, that owning a home provides.

Progressive issues focused on class tend towards Marxism, but again, this is [heavily influenced by issues of race](https://mronline.org/2018/09/12/race-class-and-social-strategy/#gsc.tab=0).

> On one part of that spectrum, as Briahna Gray writes in The Intercept, Democratic Senator Kamala Harris targets the Left’s supposed “class reductionism”; on another, socialists debate if and how the fundamental Marxist insight of class centrality can be used to formulate strategies to fight racial and gender oppression. In a recent review of Asad Haider’s book Mistaken Identity, Melissa Naschek writes that Haider rightly points to the ways in which “the ideology and rhetoric of ‘identity’ has been used as a weapon against the working class.” But while Marxists must defend class politics from both the radical and mainstream variants of what Gray in her piece calls “race reductionism,” fights for universalist class-wide demands and fights against particular racial oppressions are not mutually exclusive (as Naschek’s piece seems to imply). Indeed, in order for the socialist project to succeed, socialists must link these struggles together.

[Here](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0141363) is a paper on education outcomes, where the abstract concludes "Interventions to eliminate achievement gaps cannot fully succeed as long as social stratification caused by gender and racial discrimination is not addressed."

[This report out of Ohio University](http://www.kirwaninstitute.osu.edu/reports/2006/11_2006_ProgressivePolitics_Race.pdf) is worth reading (38 page pdf warning). It's a memo about progressive politics, and the need to identify racial issues in politics. They point out some examples where a "race-neutral" platform loses support, compared to platforms where racial issues are acknowledged. But what I want to point out is this paragraph in the opening section. I think it's relevant to OP's question that seems to want to extract out racial issues and just address "what's left":

> People  who  assert  the  race-neutral  position  are  usually  basing  their  claim  on  a  very  inadequate  definition  of  race  and  the  work  it  has  done  and  is  doing  in  society.  This  limited understanding of race assumes that it is primarily about people of color and that racism  is  primarily  about  discrimination  and  therefore  is  a  special  pleader.    Under  this  view,  race  or  racism  is  primarily  understood  to  be  a  psychosocial  event  that  occurs  between individual persons or prejudice directed at non-whites.  Accordingly, disparities may  be  addressed  by  identifying  bad,  discriminatory  actors  and  particular  victims,  and  transferring  resources  between  whites  and  non-whites.    The  assumption  is  that  this  is  to  be  done  by  taking  from  whites.    There  is  little  examination in this model as to what we need for a secure, healthy life.  Instead, we frame the solution as a zero sum game.   It is not surprising that whites resist.   To the extent that race is only about the grievances of non-whites, whites are less likely to join the discourse.

---

It would probably also be clarifying to discuss the concept of *race* in the United States. People get grouped together based on physical characteristics. But there is also a kind of social construction of race. At various points, Catholics and Jews have been considered non-white. At various points, white European immigrants have been considered non-white. At various points, South Asian immigrants with dark skin have been considered white. (There are better sources [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393328511) but [here's a pdf](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1525/ctx.2005.4.4.17) discussing these claims). Keeping this racial history in mind might help understanding the context of class issues.

---

This is not to say that race and class are the same thing. There are [many poor white people](https://fahe.org/appalachian-poverty/) and [57% of homeless veterans are white](http://nchv.org/index.php/news/media/background_and_statistics/). But do keep in mind the problem of [Intersectionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersectionality). Being Black, and being a woman, [cannot be combined to describe the experience of being a Black woman](https://monthlyreview.org/2019/01/01/black-feminism-and-the-combahee-river-collective/). In the same way, issues of poverty cannot be discussed without also taking into account issues of race.

Comment: See my edit for general comments.

Comment: @natojato you are assuming it is possible to clearly distinguish between "explicit and implicit prejudice" and "cultural, sociological, economic" factors. This answer discusses why that belief is mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

I think some of the confusion here stems from what is meant by the term "racism". Consider the following reasonable and not even mutually-exclusive definitions of racism:

1. Racism is an intention to cause harm or a judgement of inferiority *solely* on the basis of ethnicity.
2. Racism is an implicit bias for or against particular ethnic groups based on anecdotal experience and cultural zeitgeist.
3. Racism is a social outcome that negatively impacts a certain ethnic group or groups disproportionately compared to the background rate for the general population or compared to what one would expect based on population composition.

Note that these are as I said not mutually-exclusive, it's not that one of these is the "correct" definition and the others are wrong.

Now consider the coronavirus example you gave.

The first, as you've noted, is impossible to say, and unlikely. Like, so many healthcare workers are explicitly racist that they are outright denying care to African Americans on a massive scale because of it? Hard to prove, and seems implausible. The third definition applies, well, definitionally.

While like the first definition the second is difficult to prove, it's not impossible, and unlike the explicit racism case it's very much plausible that people (including healthcare workers and hiring decision-makers and police officers) are walking around with [implicit biases regarding ethnic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit-association_test).

So when people reference systemic racism they may or may not be implying that persons of power or cultural influence hold *explicitly* racist beliefs, but they are almost *always* referencing the kind of racism captured by definitions 2 and 3 above.

Comment: Here's an interesting article backing it up: https://www.aamc.org/news-insights/how-we-fail-black-patients-pain About half of all medical students believe things like "Black people's nerve endings are less sensitive" or "Black people have thicker skin". Black patients's pain and symptoms are not taken as seriously, likely because of such biases.

Comment: See my edit for general comments.

Comment: @natojato after reading your edit, I just don't think you can pull apart those kinds of things: they're too interwoven. It's a feedback loop: racism causes black people to be worse off, black people being worse off causes people to incorrectly infer that black people are inferior (even if subconscious) which is racism, which causes black people to be worse off...and while you might be able to figure out which came first, the chicken or the egg, dozens of generations in it doesn't make sense anymore to ask if eggs cause chickens or chickens cause eggs, the answer is yes.

Comment: Where do you get these definitions? And def. 3 seems to be wrong..If not then the Amish people have 4 fingers (Ellis-van-Creveld-Syndrom) because of racism?

Comment: @CuriousIndeed no, but Black males being shot by police at 2x the background rate is. Ditto for resumes with typically African-American names getting fewer interviews calls than resumes with identical credentials but "whiter" names. Attributing an obviously wrong position to someone who didn't espouse it so you can dismiss them is called strawmanning, and I don't appreciate it. If that was not your intent and you meant it as a legit question about what I meant, I'm sorry if I took it the wrong way.

Comment: @JaredSmith Can you elaborate why it would not be called racism? If racism is an "outcome" I don't see why it would not fit that case...Also please cite your source of this defintion, because it does not fit the definition put forward for example by oxford dictionary or merriam webster..

Comment: @JaredSmith This isn't compelling though because it starts from the assumption that the reason for different outcomes between ethnic groups IS racism. This implies that the only way for there to be no racism is for all ethnic groups to have the same outcomes. Evidently this is impossible without immense social pressure because different groups make different decisions regardless of individual racism within the society. Is it racism that Jewish people hold disproportionate wealth in America? Is it racism that black people are likelier to be in the NBA?

Comment: @Dastur that is (much like your comment on my other answer) a bizarrely extreme rephrasing of my point. It's like I said "some people don't like cheese" and you said "so you're saying all cheese is bad and anyone who likes it is a bad person"? I'm saying that racism exists and contributes to a disparity in outcomes. That is all. And that's *enough*.

Comment: @JaredSmith It's not a rephrasing though. My question is, how are you distinguishing between racism as you defined it: "social outcome that negatively impacts a certain ethnic group or groups disproportionately compared to the background rate for the general population or compared to what one would expect based on population composition", and different groups having different outcomes. Is it only when said outcome differences are caused by the first two kinds of racism you mention?

Comment: @JaredSmith What I took from your post is that the statement that "the third definition implies definitionally" in the case of healthcare implies that your third definition of racism applies to any scenario where we see disparate outcomes between ethnic groups. Because in spite of the differences in healthcare outcomes, we have no evidence that these differences are the result of current racism.

Comment: @Dastur https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C11&q=racism+in+healthcare+outcomes&btnG=

Comment: @JaredSmith You're not understanding my point. I am asking for clarification on the third definition you gave. What do you mean by "it's a social outcome that negatively impacts certain ethnic groups compared to background rate"? I don't understand the difference between this definition of racism and simply having disparate outcomes. And I don't understand why this would be called racism when it seems to be very different conceptually (as well as modern, thus making the language deliberate) from your other definitions. Why import connotation while modifying denotation?

Comment: @Dastur ah ok I think I see the disconnect now. The problem with the word "racism" is that it's *confusing*: people use it as a referent to related but distinct concepts, and that's what I was trying to get at in my answer. It doesn't help that some people *deliberately* equivocate between the different meaning to tar racism v3 with the negative connotations of racism v1. But none of my definitions are novel, those are all ways the word "racism" is used in modern parlance. As for the difference between this and "simply having disparate outcomes", the difference in outcomes is obviously

Comment: ...[cont'd] multifactorial, no one (worth talking to) is denying it. But in the course of trying to control things that you can control for you can start to tease out disparities in outcome that are worse than expected. For instance in the one study I linked *identical* resumes were submitted to job postings with different names: some stereotypically "black" and the others "white". The "white" names got called for interviews at a much higher rate, even though *again* the resumes were identical. So what's more likely: most hiring managers are closet KKK members or that they have implicit biases

Comment: ...[cont'd] that *in aggregate* result in worse outcomes for African Americans? *That* is what the term "systematic racism" means as far as I can tell from the way it's used. Hopefully that clarifies, and I think I see what you're asking now. I would strongly disagree though that we have as you put it "no evidence that the disparity in outcomes is due to racism". There is an entire body of peer-reviewed academic literature on that topic.

Answer (score -5):

The meta-analysis cited by user Brian Z seems to support the contention that racial discrimination exists in the job market. [Quilian et al. 2017](https://www.pnas.org/content/early/2017/09/11/1706255114)

However due to affirmative action policies the odds of being admitted to US universities is about 15 times higher for African Americans compared to Asian Americans.

> After controlling for grades, test scores, family background (legacy status), and athletic status (whether or not the student was a recruited athlete), Espenshade and Radford found that whites were three times, Hispanics six times, and blacks more than 15 times as likely to be accepted at a US university as Asian Americans.
> [Affirmative Action in the United states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirmative_action_in_the_United_States#Bias)

So does systemic / institutional racism exist? Unfortunately, due to affirmative action policies we cannot know. For example the meta analysis listed above seems to support that contention. However due race-based university admission the educational achievement cannot be directly compared between two different races.

If an Asian American has to work much harder to get a university degree than an African American due to Affirmative Action it is very likely that employer would choose an Asian American over an African American with the same education. That's racism yes, but it is also a consequence of Affirmative Action.

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear on your point? This sounds like evidence that systemic racism _does_ exist, and that it affects Asians too, despite their status as a "model minority"

Comment: Could you also be clearer about how this is "in the context of poverty", as specified in the question? I'm not seeing how poverty factors into the equation here, especially given that impoverished families in the US are less likely to be able to apply for university.

Comment: 'Unfortunately, due to affirmative action policies we cannot know'? This whole answer reads more like a screed against affirmative action than anything else. There are _MANY_ ways of measuring and studying systemic racism; college admissions are just one relatively small piece of the puzzle, and even within that piece there are plenty of ways of compensating for effects from admissions policies.

Comment: While affirmative action is racist according to most definitions of racism, I fail to see how this is answers the question

Comment: @StevenStadnicki "and even within that piece there are plenty of ways of compensating for effects from admissions policies." Can you cite studies that actually do this?Not saying it's not possible, but account for confounding needs data which AFAIK does not exist.