# Is there empirical evidence that institutional racism still plays an important role today

Tags: united-states, racism

Institutional racism definitely played its role in the 19 & 20th century, is there empirical evidence it still plays an important role today? I like this question to attract a collection of empirical evidence pertaining present day institutional racism. I'm not interested in everyday experience but sound scientific studies. Also I'm not looking for studies which are 20 years and older...

Comment: Have you read [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institutional_racism#United_States) yet?

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53866/how-does-one-parse-the-notion-of-systemic-racism-in-the-context-of-poverty)?

Comment: I have but found it pretty unsatisfying..Has this never been studied instead of looking at in cross section studies?..It seems that the underlying variable is wealth / income

Comment: I really wonder if this question shouldn't be closed as too broad. When one does just a minimum of research they find out that people of color are at a disadvantage in almost every aspect of public life in the US, but that the reasons are complex and it requires quite a lot of explanation for every single one of these aspects to refute all the racist arguments that it is "their own fault" people of color have it worse.

Comment: @Philipp The question is simple and concise. Never said its their own fault..Only questioning the relevancy of IR today..Also if you read the question you see that I explicitly stated that it played a role in the 19 & 20th century...

Comment: @CuriousIndeed This is quite an oversimplification. But it still raises the completely opinion-based question if the lack of social mobility in the united states is a form of indirect institutional racism.

Comment: But *does* it lack intent? And does intent really matter when the outcome is the same? You see how we are digging deeper and deeper, and at each level we are leaving a lot of aspects and nuances behind which would also require a more detailed explanation. That's what I meant with the question being too broad. It's just not as simple as it seems at the surface layer.

Comment: I agree..but compare it to the alleged role of institutional racism for the past events.(floyd death)..If it is not that simple maybe we should stop blaming IR for beingt (which is not proven still exists today)  the sole cause...

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. We are not here to decide if we should blame IR for something or not. We are here to answer objective questions. And this question is just not answerable without writing a whole book on the issue. I am also not debating if it exists or not. I am debating if you can sufficiently prove or disprove the existence of IR in the scope of a regular Stack Exchange answer. And currently I think we can't, because the problem is just too complex.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does one parse the notion of "systemic racism" in the context of poverty?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/53866/how-does-one-parse-the-notion-of-systemic-racism-in-the-context-of-poverty)

Answer (score 6):

There's a lot of evidence, but the two strongest and irrefutable ones are:

1. Discrimination in employment. It's been shown in studies that, **all else being equal**, an applicant with whitish names like "Greg" will receive more callbacks than a blackish name like "Lakisha". https://cos.gatech.edu/facultyres/Diversity_Studies/Bertrand_LakishaJamal.pdf. This naturally has many other implications: do black people also get passed over for promotions? Are they more likely to be laid off? Are they more uncomfortable in a work environment due to being marginalised hence they perform worse? These implications carry over to their student life and the treatment they receive on campus. It should be mentioned that there have been some attempts to discredit above study (by pointing out that if we only consider black surnames rather than first names, then there's no difference ... but one such study uses names like "Ryan Washington" as a proxy for a "black" name, which sounds highly dubious. If I hear the name "Ryan Washington", I am certainly not making the connection that Ryan is an African-American, but if I hear "Lakisha Washington", the connection is immediate.
2. **Unsubstantiated** racial profiling. While racial profiling in and of itself (arguably) is a logical method of policing, it must be substantiated with data and community experience. It many cases however, black people are shown to be targeted by police officers. A famous example is the NYC stop-and-frisk program, which targeted black people and latinos at a rate of 90 %, despite them committing crime at a rate of 74 %. That means at least 16 % points of the targeted profiling was unsubstantiated. In fact, 16 % is likely to be an underestimation, because since we *know* that there *is* racial profiling going on, that means that the previously mentioned crime rate of 74.4 % is *overestimated*, since more non-black non-latino people are probably committing crimes and getting away with it. There are many similar studies, e.g. some data indicates that in certain areas, white people commit more drug-related crimes, yet black people suffer more from drug-related arrests. This disparity could also be due to a targeted policing effort against black members of society.

A more abstract case for institutional racism is the everyday experience of black folk. Some may just be playing the victim card, but when nearly all ethnic minorities (of all origins, really) report some degrees of racial injustice or bias in their life, then there's probably some truth to it. Even if 90 % of those questioned are just playing the victim card (unlikely but let's make that assumption)... that means 10 % aren't. That's evidence.

Comment: @CuriousIndeed Regarding 2, the game-theoretic optimal strategy is to frisk at the rate of the crime rate. That is, first you spot a random car you may or may not want to frisk. There's a 50 % chance in NYC that car consists of a black/latino (actual data). Then you frisk based on their crime rate (74 %). That means that there's a 0.37 chance you frisk a black/latino and 0.13 chance you frisk a nonblack/nonlatino, and 0.5 chance you decide to let the person be. This means that you frisk blacks/latinos at a rate of (0.37)/(0.37 + 0.13) .... = ..... you guessed it: 74 %. Their crime rate.

Comment: From the study: "A similar out-going message is recorded on each of the voicemailboxes  but  each  message  is  recorded  bysomeone  of  the  appropriate  race  and  gender." So you can then verify language skills by listening to a 10s audio?

Comment: There is a difference between evidence (as by the callback study) and reported experience. Otherwise why would we conduct scientific studies?

Comment: @JJ for Transparency and Monica
at Martin Schröder.. Why did you reject my edit? Its perfect evidence for Institutional racism?? Can you elaborate? So basically you are ok with saying that some people claim IR because of experience but you delete a well sourced answer? Come on this is ridiculous...

Comment: "These implications carry over to their student life and the treatment they receive on campus. " Have you ever heard of affirmative action?

Comment: "After controlling for grades, test scores, family background (legacy status), and athletic status (whether or not the student was a recruited athlete), Espenshade and Radford found that whites were three times, Hispanics six times, and blacks more than 15 times as likely to be accepted at a US university as Asian Americans."

Comment: @CuriousIndeed 2. The reported experience *is* the evidence. 4. Affirmative action cannot change people's behavior. (2 and 4 being the numbers of your comments from top to bottom)

Comment: @yeah22 Personal experience is not evidence because of selection bias. "Affirmative action cannot change people's behavior." Can you provide a reference for this claim?